# export parameters in brightway

Tags: brightway

I am working with activities in my Brightway database that have parameters. However, when I export the database to use it in a different project using `bw2io.BW2Package.export_obj`, the parameters are "lost". Is it possible to export the parameters and reconnect them? In retrospect, I realise that I should not have used the `brightway2-parameters` package, but it would be too costly to completely change the project.